# SSL between 2 Tomcat servers

Tags: tomcat, liferay, cas

I'm currently trying to configure 2 Tomcats, one with CAS, and another one with Liferay.
I've created with OpenSSL a certificate for the CAS server, which is displayed when Liferay redirects me to the CAS page login in my browser, but when the CAS redirects me back to the Liferay, (when Liferay tries to validate the ticket CAS created), I only get a wonderful white page and the Liferay server displays "Unable to find valid certification path to requested target".
I tried creating the certificate with keytool, or adding it to a custom truststore passed to Liferay, but everything keeps failing me.

Maybe you guys could help?

Thanks.

UPDATE: I Looked at SSL trafic with wireshark, and it seems that liferay does not uses ssl to validate the CAS ticket, that explains why it can validate the certificate since the truststore is defined in the SSL connector...
But I don't know how to solve that

Comment: Did you specify property "truststoreFile" in server.xml of Liferay Portal's Tomcat? Your certificate should be imported to that truststore file. Could you also post the whole stacktrace of exception that you get?

Comment: So now I specified a truststoreFile and a password for the Liferay server, I had an error telling me that my keystore was corrupted, so I guess I have to make tomcat look on a specific keystoreFile, but do I have to create a new one for it? and then to create another custom truststore for the CAS server?

Answer (score 1):

For self-signed certificate you should specify attribute "truststoreFile" of SSL-connector in server.xml:

```
<Connector port="8443" sslProtocol="TLS" scheme="https" clientAuth="false" 
...
keystoreFile="tomcat.keystore" keystorePass="password" keyAlias="tomcat"

<!-- Here's attribute "truststoreFile" -->
truststoreFile="%JAVA_HOME%/jre/lib/security/cacerts"
... />
```

Try to use common truststore file that's located in "%JAVA_HOME%/jre/lib/security/cacerts". You should import your certificate to that truststore file with keytool command:

```
keytool -import -file tomcat.crt -alias tomcat -keystore %JAVA_HOME%/jre/lib/security/cacerts
```

Default password is "changeit". It's not necessary to specify default password in the `<connector />` tag in server.xml.

Comment: Do I have to create another keystore for the Liferay Server?
Thanks for your answers.

Comment: If two of your Tomcats share the same domain name you can use one certificate (and therefore one keystore) for both Tomcats. If domain names are different, you should generate two certificates for each domain name (but you can put both certificates in one keystore).

Comment: For now (for test purpose) both tomcats are on my localhost, so I can use the same keystore, and if I do so, I have to specify a truststore for both (which can eventually be the same for both too)?

Comment: Yes, you should have one certificate for "localhost", one keystore with this certificate, and one truststore, for example, JVM "cacerts".

Comment: Ok created a new fresh keystore, a custom truststore and a certificate, as specified in http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html#CreateKeystore

Both Connectors are like this (except for port number) :
<Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol" SSLEnabled="true"
maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" keyAlias="tomcat"
keystoreFile="D:\certs\keystore" keystorePass="passwd"
truststoreFile="D:\certs\truststore" truststorePass="passwd"/>

Still get the "path to requested target" error

Comment: Why can't you just use JVM's "cacerts" as a truststore file? Also be sure that your Liferay Portal's Tomcat is running on the JVM which "cacerts" you're using.

Comment: After adding my cert to cacerts, and changing the path in Liferay's server.xml, I get the "Unable to find valid certification path to requested target" again. My JVM is in Program Files (I run Win7), so I thought maybe the JVM could not access it, but no FileNotFoundException is prompted...